# PDF is not display in safari i-Pad

Tags: ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, object, pdf, safari

Inside my asp.net MVC web application i need to display pdf in safari browser in iPad.  my code is like this.

```
 <object data="@Model.StringPdfUrl" type="application/pdf">
                <embed src="@Model.StringPdfUrl" type="application/pdf" />
            </object>
```

Does anybody know about the fix for this issue.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution.

I used iframe to render pdf in safari

```
 if (Request.Browser.Type.Contains("Safari"))
                    {
        <iframe src="@Model.StringPdfUrl" height="750" width="600" frameborder="0" id="myiframe" ></iframe>
                    }
                    else
                    {
        <object height="750" width="600" data="@Model.StringPdfUrl" type="application/pdf">
            <embed src="@Model.StringPdfUrl" type="application/pdf" />
        </object> 
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is not the same issue I once had with Internet Explorer.

Even with the latest IE 11, if the url doesn't end with the extension `.pdf` (which was the case with my MVC app: the url was like `/File/Download/4587`), then IE plug-in could not render the PDF file. Same issue with `<embed>`.

I tried the `iframe` solution, but on some computers the document opened up in a new window.

In the end, the solution I implemented was to convert each page of the PDF document into an image with `GhostscriptSharp`, and then to render the document online as images in an HTML page (with navigation controls to go to first/previous/next/last page).